# how to concatenate to mysql_query onclick td

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have a mysql_query in PHP. it works when I insert a name of a user manually.

What I want to do now is using a table dynamically made from mysql DB I select a cell which has a name and then this name is concatenated to the mysql_query. How do I go about doing this? I have looked for examples but cannot find anything on using table cell to add to the 
mysql_query to retrieve data.

E.G.

```
select * from cars were car='bmw'
```

Now if I have a table of cars when I click a mercedes the bmw will be mercedes in the query.

Comment: sounds like you're leaving the SQL Injection door wide open

Comment: how is that possible when the users only input is a table with 1 column and x rows- the rows will have uneditable data.

Comment: the UI is locked, but anyone could either issue a request without going through the UI, or even just use a browser's element inspector to modify the markup and then submit it.  Once the client has access, you lose control.

Comment: @user1783326 You do not need editable data to perform SQL injections.  mysql_query is unsecure and has begun depreciation.  Research using PDO or msqli_*, as well as POST and GET to generate search results.  You can also use AJAX and JavaScript to trigger your server side functions at a specific time (onClick for example).

Comment: As an FYI that is nice to know so thanks, but this is just a simple app sql injection is an element which is not considered in this instance

Comment: What the heck are you talking about? Even the title does not make any sense, I mean, what's a DOM element (td), event (onclick) have to do with server-side MySQL (mysql_query)?

Comment: The queston I had was when I have a sql query such as select * from cars were car="". In the "" how do I append a table cells value?

Comment: You need to use javscript. Better check [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: thanks air4x il give that a go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a 'simple' app, a simple method of completing your task is to use `POST` or `GET`.  When you dynamically create your table based off of your search results, try dumping your results as hyperlinks that direct back to your script (or a different script) and use `$_GET`.

This example is totally hypothetical because I don't have a lot to go off of based on your OG questions.  Here you are creating your table and dumping your results:

```
$run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars");
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
    $car = $row['car'];
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<a href='searchByCar.php?car=$car'>$car</a>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table";
```

Now that you have your results as hyperlinks that the user can click, use the following on the `searchByCar.php` so that you can gather what they selected and use it:

```
$selected_car = $_GET['car'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car='$selected_car'";
```

This should at least get you started but you should research `GET`, as well as look into `POST` and `AJAX`.  This example will also be useless in the near future when `mysql_*` is not supported.  You should really look into using `PDO` or `MySQLi` (or at least learn about them).  I would type out examples for those but there is plenty of content that you can find by using [Google.com](http://www.google.com).  To get you started, try checking this out: [PDO vs MySQLI: Which Should You Use?](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)